# Lower noise in picture to enable OCR with tesseract

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to do OCR on this kind of images:

[image]

Unfortunately, tesseract is unable to retrieve the number because of the noisy points arround the characters.

I tried playing with ImageMagick to enhance the quality of the image but no luck.

Examples:

```
 convert input.tif -level 0%,150% output.tif

 convert input.tif -colorspace CMYK -separate output_%d.tif
```

[image]

Is there any way to retrieve efficiently the characters in this kind of images?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple [closing operation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html)(Dilation followed by Erosion) will give you desired output. Below is the Python implementation of the same.

```
img = cv2.imread(r'D:\Image\noiseOCR.png',0)
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
```

[image: Denoised Output image]

Answer (score 1):

Digits in this image are largest connected components. So another approach is doing the connected component analysis.